# for loop prints out all contents not just the last added into list box... any reason why?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

for loop prints out all contents not just the last added into list box... any reason why??

```
def changeCss():
    readingCss = open(FileName.get()+'.css','r')
    FileContentsCss = readingCss.readlines()
    readingCss.close()
    index = 0
    while index < len(FileContentsCss):
        FileContentsCss[index]= FileContentsCss[index].rstrip('\n')
        index +=1
    while '' in FileContentsCss:
        FileContentsCss.remove('')  
    for cont in FileContentsCss:
        Open.insert(END, cont + '\n')
```

Comment: Note about style: variable names should start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation: On `for` loop

The for loop iterates through all the elements in a list

Example:

```
list1 = ['hello', 'world']
for ele in list1:
    print(ele)
```

or

Using slicing, we can specify the start index and end index to make `for loop` iterate through all the elements between those indexes

```
l1 = ['hello', 'world', 'good']
for a in l1[1:3]:
    print(a)
```

For the above query if you want to print the last added element in the list:

```
l1 = ['hello', 'world', 'good']
l1.append('morning')
for a in l1[-1::1]:
    print(a)
```

Output:

```
morning
```